# Woocommerce add Attributes to a specifc Hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I do have that code:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'wtom_show_attributes_title', 15);

function wtom_show_attributes_title() {
    global $product;

    $abv = $product->get_attribute ('pa_weingut');
    $abb = $product->get_attribute ('pa_weinart');

    echo __($abv, $abb, 'woocommerce');
}
```

It returns only the first attribute `pa_weingut`, how can I make an output to show both attributes? And how do I add a css class to the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the __() function only takes to input arguments, but you're giving it 3. Why don't you call it twice?

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'wtom_show_attributes_title', 15);

function wtom_show_attributes_title()
{
 global $product;

    $abv = $product->get_attribute ('pa_weingut');
    $abb = $product->get_attribute ('pa_weinart');

    echo "<div class='someclassname'>" . __($abv,'woocommerce') . "</div>";
    echo "<div class='someclassname'>" . __($abb,'woocommerce') . "</div>";
}
```